# Integrate Third Party tool with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can integrate particular Third party tool with my vb.net application

Comment: We would need more specifics to give you an effective answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using Interop you can do Call Shell("tool.exe")

Answer (score 0):

More details are definitely required, if you're still interested, but roughly speaking it depends on whether by 'integrate' you mean just triggering another application from yours or do you actually require back 'n' forth communication between these apps, whatever they are.

I can't remember the VB.NET specifics and I don't have it available right now, but in C# you could simply trigger another application like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start("<shell command, e.g. fred.exe>");
```